# Python. Частота появления слов и букв независимо от их регистра в тексте который находиться в файле

Tags: python

Нужно написать программу, которая будет анализировать частоту с которой
в тексте(в файле) будут встречаться отдельные буквы или слова независимо от их регистра и выводить в консоль потом записывать в новый файл.

Для начала:

```py
with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as file:
    text = file.read()
    text = text.replace("\n", " ")
    text = text.replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace(":", "").replace(";", "").replace("?", "").replace("!", "")
    text = text.lower()
    words = text.split()
```

Таким образом получаем текст из файла и убираем всё лишние из текста, а дальше как правильно сделать не понимаю....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Для слов

```py
from collections import Counter
import re

words = re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())
cnt = Counter(words).most_common(10) # для примера 10 самых популярных
with open("new.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(cnt)
```

#### Для букв

Тоже самое, но для паттерна для модуля `re` использовать отдельные буквы. В зависимоти от того насколько большой текст, возможно, стоит отказаться для подсчета букв от данного модуля и использовать конструкцию

```py
str.count("a")
```

И использовать перебор по всем буквам алфавита

```py
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

cnt = Counter()
for letter in letters:
    cnt[letter] = text.lower().count(letter)
```

Запись организовать как указано выше

и так далее, для чисел, для знаков и прочее

Чтобы удалить все знаки препинания, тоже можно воспользоваться модулем `re`

```py
import re

text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text)
```

Теперь если все объеденить

```py
import re
import json
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

# чтение
def read_file(path):
    result = None
    with open(path, encoding="utf8") as file:
        text = file.read().lower()
        result = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', text)  # это излишнее можно удалить, только для примера использую
    return result

def find_words(text):
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', text)
    cnt = Counter(words)
    return dict(cnt)

def find_letters(text):
    cnt = Counter()
    for letter in letters:
        cnt[letter] = text.count(letter)
    return dict(cnt)

# запись
def write_file(all_entities, path):
    with open(path, "w") as file:
        json.dump(all_entities, file, indent = 4)

# Основная логика
file = read_file("test_data.txt")
words = find_words(file)
letters = find_letters(file)
common_dict = {"words":words, "letters":letters}
write_file(common_dict, "new_file.txt")
```

Пример результирующего файла на тексте рыбе

```json
{
    "words": {
        "but": 4,
        "i": 2,
        "must": 1,
        "explain": 1,
        "to": 7,
        "you": 2,
        "how": 2,
        "all": 1,
        "this": 1,
        "mistaken": 1,
        "idea": 1,
        "of": 7,
        "denouncing": 1,
        "pleasure": 7,
        "and": 4,
        "praising": 1,
        "pain": 5,
        "was": 1,
        "born": 1,
        "will": 1,
        "give": 1,
        "a": 5,
        "complete": 1,
        "account": 1,
        "the": 5,
        "system": 1,
        "expound": 1,
        "actual": 1,
        "teachings": 1,
        "great": 2,
        "explorer": 1,
        "truth": 1,
        "masterbuilder": 1,
        "human": 1,
        "happiness": 1,
        "no": 3,
        "one": 2,
        "rejects": 1,
        "dislikes": 1,
        "or": 4,
        "avoids": 2,
        "itself": 2,
        "because": 4,
        "it": 3,
        "is": 3,
        "those": 1,
        "who": 5,
        "do": 1,
        "not": 1,
        "know": 1,
        "pursue": 1,
        "rationally": 1,
        "encounter": 1,
        "consequences": 2,
        "that": 3,
        "are": 1,
        "extremely": 1,
        "painful": 1,
        "nor": 1,
        "again": 1,
        "there": 1,
        "anyone": 1,
        "loves": 1,
        "pursues": 1,
        "desires": 1,
        "obtain": 2,
        "occasionally": 1,
        "circumstances": 1,
        "occur": 1,
        "in": 1,
        "which": 2,
        "toil": 1,
        "can": 1,
        "procure": 1,
        "him": 1,
        "some": 2,
        "take": 1,
        "trivial": 1,
        "example": 1,
        "us": 1,
        "ever": 1,
        "undertakes": 1,
        "laborious": 1,
        "physical": 1,
        "exercise": 1,
        "except": 1,
        "advantage": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "has": 2,
        "any": 1,
        "right": 1,
        "find": 1,
        "fault": 1,
        "with": 1,
        "man": 1,
        "chooses": 1,
        "enjoy": 1,
        "annoying": 1,
        "produces": 1,
        "resultant": 1
    },
    "letters": {
        "a": 74,
        "b": 13,
        "c": 32,
        "d": 17,
        "e": 93,
        "f": 13,
        "g": 10,
        "h": 33,
        "i": 53,
        "j": 2,
        "k": 5,
        "l": 33,
        "m": 14,
        "n": 56,
        "o": 68,
        "p": 27,
        "q": 2,
        "r": 43,
        "s": 59,
        "t": 61,
        "u": 42,
        "v": 7,
        "w": 13,
        "x": 7,
        "y": 11,
        "z": 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы подсчитать частоту элементов в коллекции можете воспользовать следующим примером кода:

```py
from functools import reduce

def count_frequencies(sequence):
    def increment_item_frequency(freqs, item):
        freqs[item] = freqs.get(item, 0) + 1
        return freqs

    freqs = reduce(increment_item_frequency, sequence, {})
    return freqs

# Пример работы
x = [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5]
print(count_frequencies(x))
```

Если вы хотите подсчитать слова - передайте в `count_frequencies` список всех слов. Если хотите буквы - передавайте буквы (можно просто строку).